# Passing Variable from JSON data

Tags: javascript, ios, titanium

I am building a mobile app using Titanium for ios and I am having a tough time getting my arms wrapped around passing variables. I am using a combination of local database and remote database to deliver my data. In this case I want to pass the data on the tableViewRow selected. The label that displays the data I call "categorydescription". In my table.addEventListener, I want to pass that data as the title for the new window and I will pass that same data to my php file on the remote server. Here is the code I am trying to use:

```
var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
onload: function() {
Ti.API.debug(this.responseText);

var json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
for (i = 0; i < json.cms_client.length; i++) {
    client = json.cms_client[i];
    row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
        height:'44dp',
        hasChild:true
    });

var categorydescription = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        text:client.catdesc,
        font:{fontSize:'16dp', fontWeight:'bold'},
    height:'auto',
    left:'10dp',
    color:'#000'
    });

row.add(categorydescription);
    tableData.push(row);
}
table.addEventListener('click',function(e) {
    var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({url: 'clients.js', title: ??});
    var catdesc = ??;
    win.catdesc = catdesc;
    Titanium.UI.currentTab.open(win,{animated:true});
}); 
 table.setData(tableData);
```

Would someone be so kind to tell me what I need to put in place of the ?? in the 'title' and 'var catdesc' above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the category description and title to the row object itself:

```
row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
    height:'44dp',
    hasChild:true,
    categoryDescription : client.catdesc, //Add this
    clientTitle : client.title // Add this
});
```

Now get them in the listener:

```
table.addEventListener('click',function(e) {
    var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({url: 'clients.js', title: e.row.title});
    var catdesc = e.row.categoryDescription;
    win.catdesc = catdesc;
    Titanium.UI.currentTab.open(win,{animated:true});
});
```

Comment: Thank you Josiah, I appreciate your explanation as I was having a difficult time understanding how to apply other posts that I read.